# (PHP) Ixudra/Curl cannot post file

Tags: php, laravel, rest, curl

I am using Ixudra/Curl in my laravel project.
I have an issue when I try to upload a file to a Java API.
With Curl Using command line is working file with:

```
curl -X POST \
http://<<api url>>' \
-H 'Content-Type: multipart/form-data' \
-H 'cache-control: no-cache' \
-H 'content-type: multipart/form-data; boundary=xxxxx\
-F 'data={"tables" : ... (no need to post all data)' \
-F 'file=@C:\Users\UserName\Downloads\Test.xls'
```

With PHP code I am trying without success:

```
Curl::to('<<api url>>')
     ->withContentType('multipart/form-data; boundary=' . hash('sha256', uniqid('', true)))
     ->withData(array('data' => {"tables" : ...  ))
     ->withFile('file', 'C:\Users\UserName\Downloads\Test.xls', 'application/vnd.ms-excel', 'Test.xls')
     ->post();
```

The response I am getting with this code is:

**"exception":"org.springframework.web.multipart.support.MissingServletRequestPartException","message":"Required request part 'file' is not present"**

Any idea? Thanks for your time

Comment: I have not worked with this package, but u can try to use `guzzle/http`. I think it should solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved,
Seems this library didn't like that I specify the content-type.
Once I deleted that line, everything worked as expected